# Why does global spaceship operator not behave as expected?

Tags: c++, clang, standards, c++20, spaceship-operator

```
#include <compare>
#include <forward_list>

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    std::forward_list<T> l;
};

template<typename T>
auto operator<=>(const A<T>& lhs, const A<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.l <=> rhs.l;
}

int main()
{
    std::forward_list<int>{} < std::forward_list<int>{}; // ok

    A<int>{} < A<int>{}; // error
}
```

Compiled with `clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ main.cpp` and error messages:

```
main.cpp:13:18: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const std::forward_list<int>' and 'const std::forward_list<int>')
    return lhs.l <=> rhs.l;
           ~~~~~ ^   ~~~~~
main.cpp:20:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'operator<=><int>' requested here
    A<int>{} < A<int>{}; // error
```

**Why does global spaceship operator not behave as expected?**

Comment: Can you make the question text more specific to the actual question? What is "not expected"? In this case the question seems to be "Why can't I invoke `<=>` on a `std::forward_list`?" The global spaceship operator seems to behave exactly as you wanted - it got invoked after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not seem that libc++ (or any of the standard libraries) implements the spaceship operator library additions completely yet.

See [here for libc++](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx2a_status.html) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) for a compiled table at cppreference.com. The relevant paper adding the `operator<=>` to `std::forward_list` is P1614.

If you look at libc++'s source code for `std::forward_list` [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/forward_list), you see that there is no mention of `operator<=>` yet and the other secondary comparison operators are still defined unconditionally (which should not be the case in C++20).

`std::forward_list<int>{} < std::forward_list<int>{};` compiles because it uses `operator<`, not `operator<=>`. If you tried `std::forward_list<int>{} <=> std::forward_list<int>{}` directly, it would fail as well (in the current state of libc++).